# How to create images from DOM (SPA) in the server?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, single-page-application, serverside-javascript, server-side-rendering

This is the problem we have. We have a spa and there are some pages that generates some reports. Those pages allows users to download some graphics generated by the spa. The download can be done with a word (docxtemplater), pdf (pdfmake) or just images files (jszip and download.js). All this is done by the spa (in the browser). There are two problems: as users start to add more data then the download is taking more time to render. And we have seen there are some incompatibilities due to some browser/OS versions. The main issue comes from generating images from the dom. We are using html2canvas (slow) and dom-to-images (fast but only working in chrome for us now - we had some issue when trying to generate images from some google charts).

What we are looking for now is to move all this into the server so we can have a controlled environment so it has support for IE, Safari, Firefox and Chrome. The idea is to generate all these files in the server.

I've read we could accomplish this by using [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/), [phantomcloud](https://phantomjscloud.com/index.html) or [nightmare](http://www.nightmarejs.org/). Our backend is REST using java. So, before I dag into this, I'd like to know if anyone has experienced a similar issue or can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Not sure on specific tech to solve your problem, but generating those documents should be possible via some existing java libraries. If not, you could always spin up a node application that uses the libraries you're already comfortable with for that purpose. The only thing is you would need to consider where that gets hosted, how it shares data, etc.

Comment: A project where I work does exactly this, creating PDFs on the server, think it uses phantom but not 100%. You might want to check out headless chrome which has just come out if that's your preferred browser.

Comment: @agmcleod Thanks for he reply. Yeah, I know there are java libraries to generate those files(word, pdf...) the main issue here is how to get images from the dom in the server so we no longer take the images from the user browsers. I'm doing the phantom way and I see a new host will be needed and probably a new phantom version of the page.

Comment: Thanks @Matt. I'll take a look at headless chrome in case I see difficult to connect phantomjs with java (I see there is a phatomjs driver - ghostdriver - that may work directly with java)